# Does using ffmpeg reduce the quality of the video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using a code like that to convert a sequence of images into a video.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i a%04d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -b 40000k video.mp4
```

I noticed that the size of the output video is much less than the total size of the images. Does that mean there's a reduction in the quality?

Comment: ffmepg is the tool. The quality depends on the codec, not the tool.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thanks for replying. So you mean the reduction in video size necessarily means a reduction in quality?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I merely pointed out how confused is your question.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/421295/114058 - especially the section on temporal redundancy

Comment: @Gyan Thanks, so the reduction in size is because that only changes in animation are considered and no need to process or save the whole frame/image. This way, the quality will not be affected, right?

Comment: Basically, yes.